# i have faced the issue while creating triple y-axis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

i have faced the problem while creating triple y-axis in google charts .
The problem is space between right side axis. could you please help me.

i provided the following code snippet. In result, right y-axes are merged .could you provide what is way to give space /gap between them to look good. Thank you

```js
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line', 'corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', 'Month');
      data.addColumn('number', "Average Temperature");
      data.addColumn('number', "Average Hours of Daylight");
   data.addColumn('number', "Average 1");
      data.addColumn('number',"Average 2")
      data.addRows([
        [new Date(2014, 0),  -.5,  8.7,7,11],
        [new Date(2014, 1),   .4,  8.7,5,12],
        [new Date(2014, 2),   .5,   12,6,13],
        [new Date(2014, 3),  2.9, 15.7,5,14],
        [new Date(2014, 4),  6.3, 18.6,8,15],
        [new Date(2014, 5),    9, 20.9,8,16],
        [new Date(2014, 6), 10.6, 19.8,9,16],
        [new Date(2014, 7), 10.3, 16.6,7,15],
        [new Date(2014, 8),  7.4, 13.3,8,14],
        [new Date(2014, 9),  4.4,  9.9,12,13],
        [new Date(2014, 10), 1.1,  6.6,11,12],
        [new Date(2014, 11), -.2,  4.5,11,11]
      ]);

   

      var classicOptions = {
        title: 'Average Temperatures and Daylight in Iceland Throughout the Year',
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        // Gives each series an axis that matches the vAxes number below.
        series: {
          0: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
          1: {targetAxisIndex: 1},
          2: {targetAxisIndex: 2},
          3: {targetAxisIndex: 3}
        },
        vAxes: {
          // Adds titles to each axis.
          0: {title: 'Temps (Celsius)'},
          1: {title: 'Daylight'},
          2: {title: 'third'},
          3: {title: 'foruth'}
        },
        hAxis: {
          ticks: [new Date(2014, 0), new Date(2014, 1), new Date(2014, 2), new Date(2014, 3),
                  new Date(2014, 4),  new Date(2014, 5), new Date(2014, 6), new Date(2014, 7),
                  new Date(2014, 8), new Date(2014, 9), new Date(2014, 10), new Date(2014, 11)
                 ]
        },
        vAxis: {
          viewWindow: {
            max: 30
          }
        }
      };


        var classicChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        classicChart.draw(data, classicOptions);

    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <br><br>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Could you show us some code? What have you tried?

Comment: Share your code snippet and some more details so people can help you.

Comment: @Santosh http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

i'm thinking this feature was intended for no more than two `vAxes`,
although it does appear to work, there aren't any config options to handle this

if you must have three, try `textPosition`

have one `'in'` and the other `'out'`

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Month');
    data.addColumn('number', "Average Temperature");
    data.addColumn('number', "Average Hours of Daylight");
    data.addColumn('number', "Average 1");
    data.addColumn('number',"Average 2")
    data.addRows([
      [new Date(2014, 0),  -.5,  8.7,7,11],
      [new Date(2014, 1),   .4,  8.7,5,12],
      [new Date(2014, 2),   .5,   12,6,13],
      [new Date(2014, 3),  2.9, 15.7,5,14],
      [new Date(2014, 4),  6.3, 18.6,8,15],
      [new Date(2014, 5),    9, 20.9,8,16],
      [new Date(2014, 6), 10.6, 19.8,9,16],
      [new Date(2014, 7), 10.3, 16.6,7,15],
      [new Date(2014, 8),  7.4, 13.3,8,14],
      [new Date(2014, 9),  4.4,  9.9,12,13],
      [new Date(2014, 10), 1.1,  6.6,11,12],
      [new Date(2014, 11), -.2,  4.5,11,11]
    ]);

    var classicOptions = {
      title: 'Average Temperatures and Daylight in Iceland Throughout the Year',
      width: 900,
      height: 500,
      chartArea: {
        width: '50%'
      },
      series: {
        0: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
        1: {targetAxisIndex: 1},
        2: {targetAxisIndex: 2}
      },
      vAxes: {
        0: {
          textPosition: 'out',
          title: 'Temps (Celsius)'
        },
        1: {
          textPosition: 'in',
          title: 'Daylight',
          viewWindow: {
            max: 30
          }
        },
        2: {
          textPosition: 'out',
          title: 'third',
          viewWindow: {
            max: 40
          }
        }
      },
      hAxis: {
        ticks: [
          new Date(2014, 0), new Date(2014, 1), new Date(2014, 2), new Date(2014, 3),
          new Date(2014, 4),  new Date(2014, 5), new Date(2014, 6), new Date(2014, 7),
          new Date(2014, 8), new Date(2014, 9), new Date(2014, 10), new Date(2014, 11)
        ]
      },
    };

    var classicChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    classicChart.draw(data, classicOptions);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```